# Capabilities.screenDPI: correct on emulator, wrong on device

Tags: layout, actionscript, flex-mobile, multiscreen

I'm making my app multi-screen (flex mobile). Basicly I want to know when I'm dealing with a tablet or a smartphone. Therefore I want to know the screen size in inch. I'm testing this out on a Desire HD (4.3 inch). My issue is: when I use the Capabilities.screenDPI, the emulator shows the correct value (217), however when I run this on my device, it gives me a wrong DPI value (240), the width and height are correct. Based on that dpi I get a wrong screen size in inch (3.887" != 4.3"). Again on the emulator everything runs fine. The device emulator is configured with the correct values, only when I run it on the real device (no emulator), I get a wrong DPI value.

I'm calculating it with the following piece of code:

```
var screenX:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var screenY:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var pixels:Number = (screenX*screenX) + (screenY*screenY);
var screenSize:Number = Math.sqrt(pixels)/Capabilities.screenDPI;

return (screenSize >= 6) ? "tablet" : "phone"
```

To spare you some time I'll give out the values of the Desire HD:

> 480 x 800 pixels, 4.3 inches (~217 ppi pixel density)

The formula used is simple ~ Pythagoras: a2 + b2 = c2 -> sqrt(c)/dpi = screen size in inch.

Based on Adobe, the DPI or PPI value can be used "interchangeably". ([Adobe, Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html)). I haven't found any information wherether the dpi value is different than the ppi value, or wherether there is any possibility to use a ppi property in flex.

So on my real device I get:

> 480 x 800 pixels, 3.89" (~240 dpi).

**Another note:**
I've seen that there are 3 default constants in flex mobile. Might it be that its directly thrown into one of these ? (I don't suspect so since I'm calling the Capabilities.screenDPI directly).

```
DPIClassification.DPI_160
DPIClassification.DPI_240
DPIClassification.DPI_320
```

**What I mean is: How can I determine if it's a tablet or phone (in order to switch to another layout)? You can't follow the `applicationDPI` road, since it's all mixed up with new devices like the Samsung Galaxy S3 (1280x720, 319 PPI) or the Apple iPad 3 (2048×1536, 264 PPI).**

Comment: An old thread but this is really an issue, but not so many resources. A work around was just to create different views for mobile and tablets. As mentioned DPI is no longer reliable solution because of the wide range of dpis on tablets and mobile phones. You can work using DPIs if you will separate the views for mobiles and tablets (just check for the screen size).

Answer (score 4):

To detect the screen size in emulator mode you can use SystemManager object this way :

```
var root:DisplayObject = SystemManager.getSWFRoot(this); // this is any object of the application not only display object
screenX = root.stage.fullScreenWidth;
screenY = root.stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I thought you guys would want to know how I handled it - I finally have it fixed on my end.

```
protected function resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {
                var screenX:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
                var screenY:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
                var osType:String = Capabilities.os;
                var limitNumber:Number = 960;
                var pixelCheck:Number = screenX * screenY;
                var pixels:Number = (screenX*screenX) + (screenY*screenY);
                var screenSize:Number = Math.sqrt(pixels)/Capabilities.screenDPI;

                isPortrait = height > width;
                //isTablet = screenX > limitNumber || screenY > limitNumber;
                isTablet = screenSize >= 6;
                var isDesktop:Boolean = height > limitNumber || width > limitNumber;

                if (osType.toUpperCase() == "WINDOWS 7"){
                    this.currentState = (isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape") + (isDesktop ? "Tablet" : "Phone");
                }else {
                    this.currentState = (isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape") + (isTablet ? "Tablet" : "Phone");
                }

                //DEBUGGING CODE BELOW


                debugger.text = "screen X: " + screenX.toString() + " screen Y: " + screenY.toString() + "\n pixels: " + pixels.toString() + "\n screenSize: " + screenSize.toString() + "\n capabilities.screenDPI: " + Capabilities.screenDPI.toString() + "\n current state: " + this.currentState + /*"\n IsDesktop: " + isDesktop.toString() + */ " IsTablet: " + isTablet.toString() + "\n OS Type" + osType;

                //currentState = (isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape") + (isTablet ? "Tablet" : "Phone");

            }
```

As you can see from the code above, I'm handling two different situations.  1 - when I am using the emulator on my local PC, the system always thinks im in tablet mode (because it returns very large values for my monitors' screen X and screen Y values).  So I handle that with the isDesktop flag.

Then, I use the screen size value to give me tablet vs phone.  There are currently (Feb 2013) no tablets under 6 for the screen size, and no phones above it.

Answer (score 0):

The Flex [applicationDPI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#applicationDPI) property will return either 160 (for most tablets), 240 (for most smartphones), and 320 for the iPhone 4/4S.

This is something that occurs under the hood to make life "Easier" for developers.  Anything built for the specific DPI of the device may not be very expandable to other devices/platforms.  I thought that the applicationDPI into one of those 3 values was a Flex thing, but it's entirely possible Flex just inherits it from AIR.

At the end of the day, I don't think there is any way you can use the DPI value to determine whether your app is running on a tablet or phone.  Because the values I specify above are not universal.  It's all a bit of a guessing game.

I'm surprised this works at all in the emulator, where I would expect the values returned to be the ones from your computer monitor, not equivalent to what the smartphone should be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The emulator shows the correct values since different devices are specified in Flash Builder (phones and tablets), each one with a width x height and a DPI. What surprises me that the emulator shows the correct DPI value, resulting in the real screen size -> 4.3 inch, and the real device gives me the applicationDPI value, when I use the Capabilities.screenDPI property. The thing is I don't want to use the `applicationDPI` property. I need the correct DPI/PPI in order to get the size in inch. In order to switch for example to another layout with a `SplitViewNavigator`.

Comment: What I mean is: How can I determine if it's a tablet or phone (in order to switch to another layout)? You can't follow the `applicationDPI` road, since it's all mixed up with new devices like the Samsung Galaxy S3 (1280x720, 319 PPI) or the Apple iPad 3 (2048×1536, 264 PPI).

Comment: In the Flash Builder emulator, the Capabilities.screenResolutionX and screenResolutionY will show the values of your monitor; not the values of the emulated device.  I'm surprised this value is wrong, but the DPI value is correct.  But, I'll take your word for it.  As far as I know, there is no way to determine if it's an app is running on a tablet or a phone; for the same reasons you specify. You can't count on DPI; and you can't count on resolution.

Comment: I use the stage.stageWidth and height. Those values are correct in the emulator, the dpi is also correct in the emulator. The stage.stageWidth and height are correct on the real phone, but the dpi is wrong.

Comment: @kim StageWidth and StageHeight should be right, of course, since the emulator will be sized similar to the device.  However, those values will not always be the resolution of the device, only the space that is allotted for your application.  I thought on some Android devices, you may have space above or below the app for the system footer / menu bars.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
var isItATablet:Boolean = screenHeight > 960 || screenWidth > 960;
var isItReallyATablet:Boolean = isTablet && screenDPI >= 240; // I think this doesn't work as is, but you get the idea..
```

This way you get if the screen height or width is greater than 960px and the DPI is low, probably you're on a tablet.

This is not 100% accurate, a haven't tested it but on 2 devices, it's just matter of trying with different devices and see if it guess the type of device on most cases